Specific URL cant resolve in browsers but works in Postman
Im having a weird problem with a specific url that I cant resolve in all my browsers on my Mac. The specific url is: https://cdn.forzaco.com/Test.jpg
In both Firefox, Chrome and Safari I get:
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

The weird part is that its working when I do a GET request in Postman. I've tried to flush my DNS and restart. I've also tried on multiple networks. Its working fine from other devices on the same network. Any suggestions on how I can debug this issue?

TLS/SSL problem? You should get more detailed connection logging from either side.
